# How to correclty use Views in different folders. (The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

My App has 3 big modules, one for the global admin, one for the company admin, and one for the company user.

I want to split this into folders, both in the controllers folder and inside the views folder.

When I add the controller with scaffolding.
http://screencast.com/t/zxK5kaWLY

It will automatically create a folder with the name of the Model inside the views folder.
http://screencast.com/t/JsSxGjkFw5h3

However, I want to organize it like this, so I moved the files
http://screencast.com/t/8n24rU7n2fbI

But when I try to run it  I get this error:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

> ~/Views/Empresas/Index.aspx ~/Views/Empresas/Index.ascx
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
> ~/Views/Empresas/Index.cshtml ~/Views/Empresas/Index.vbhtml
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

The reason I want to organize it that way its because the app will be huge, with lots of controllers per module, so its easier to find.

Comment: Use Areas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split your application using Areas:

[Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)